# Looping through Javascript Method and add data to the Method

Tags: javascript

I have a Array of Month Values inside JavaScript .

```
var myarray = new Array();


myarray2.push("January");
myarray2.push("February");
myarray2.push("March");
myarray2.push("April");
myarray2.push("May");
myarray2.push("Jun");
myarray2.push("Jul");
myarray2.push("Aug");
myarray2.push("Sept");
myarray2.push("Oct");
```

How can i loop through this Array and add inside my addAxis Method ??

Currently i have added it statically as shown , but how can i add them dynamically ??

```
chart1.addAxis("x", {
        fixLower: "none", 
        fixUpper: "none", 
        natural: true,
        majorTick: { length: 3 },
        labels: [
            {value: 1, text: "January"}, 
            {value: 2, text: "February"},
            {value: 3, text: "March"}, 
            {value: 4, text: "April"},
            {value: 5, text: "May"},
            {value: 6, text: "Jun"},
            {value: 7, text: "Jul"},
            {value: 8, text: "Aug"},
            {value: 9, text: "Sept"},
            {value: 10, text: "Oct"}

        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var i, l, labels = [];
for (i = 0, l = months.length; i < l; ++i) {
    labels.push({value : i + 1, text : months[i]});
}
```

And now the `labels` variable should have the data in the format you want.